# C/C++ intellisense 0.26.1 not displaying list of struct members

Tags: c++, c, intellisense

C/C++ intellisense is only displaying suggestions of struct members after i type some letter that is in their names, then it suggests possible matches. However, i would like it to show every possible struct member as soon as . or -> is typed. Is this a setting i`m missing?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just found out this only happens if i am trying to introduce a line between two finished lines of code (both ending with ;). Maybe intellisense does not work then because it sees a compile-time error?